# yii2 phone number validation?

Tags: regex, validation, yii2

i want phone number field accept only first five numbers and one space after that accept six numbers for example(12345 123456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(\d{5} \d{6})
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/nuWjNg/1

Or if numbers does not start with newline:

```
(?<!(\d))(\d{5} \d{6})
```

see demo: https://regex101.com/r/nuWjNg/2

Comment: it make some issue.it's accept greater than five and greater than six length also.but put less less than five and less than six means it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/A18snt/1) and a little script is enough for this validation.

**Regex: ^\d{5} \d{6}$**